# How to get a domain with multiples points?

Tags: web, dns

I want buy a domain for example **chat.com**, but how to get a domain with more one points.

for example:

**web.chat.com**

What i need for this ? Is programming or is some type of domain services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your example "web" is a subdomain, you can set up as many of these as you want IF you own the domain (chat.com)

so just buy the domain you want (chat.com is probably not available)

then you set up your subdomains with your DNS-provider (often the same place where you buy your domain), the subdomains then "point" to one or more servers where you host your web-pages, apps, api:s ...

if you point more than one subdomain to the same server you can configure the web server (e.g. apache) to handle traffic to the different subdomains.

Comment: thanks, then i need of domain chat.com, the hard is find a free domain, or that dont will be premium. I thought that will be a different domain with more points.

Comment: what you think better ? web-chat.com or chat.net ? Because chat.com is not avaliable, remembering that chat.com is a example.

Comment: finding a good domain is very hard, but think about the most successful services you know, flickr.com, not pictures.com. facebook.com not sharewithfriends.com..